# Controlling anchors/curves in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been looking for a method to control the curves and/or anchors within a path, drawn by usage of curveTo for example.

Basically, when I draw something like this:

```
thingy.graphics.curveTo(220,100,150,140);
thingy.graphics.curveTo(60,200,50,300);
thingy.graphics.curveTo(40,495,250,500);
thingy.graphics.curveTo(460,495,450,300);
```

I'd like to dynamically change these curves when I do something in a function (for example dragging an anchor point). In other words, I simply want to update the coordinates of a certain curve, like:

overwriting

```
thingy.graphics.curveTo(220,100,150,140);
```

to

`thingy.graphics.curveTo(120,100,250,670);`

or

`thingy.graphics.curveTo(220,100,mouseX,mouseY);`

for instance.

While Googling for an answer to my question I've only been able to find long articles with very complex formulas, most of the time not even accompanied by any bit of AS3 code. As I am not very good with maths, I'd prefer a simple answer that just shows a method to do this.

Alternatively, I wouldn't mind controlling curves drawn in the Flash IDE instead, if that's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach it.

```
private var curveVals:Array = [];

private var thingy:Sprite;

public function constructor() {
   thingy = new Sprite();

   var obj:Object = {cx:220,cy:100,ax:150,ay:140}
   curveVals.push(obj);
   thingy.graphics.curveTo(220,100,150,140);

   obj = {cx:60,cy:200,ax:50,ay:300}
   curVals.push(obj);
   thingy.graphics.curveTo(60,200,50,300);
}

private function storeVals(cx,cy,ax,ay,index):void {
    var obj:Object = {cx:cx,cy:cy,ax:ax,ay:ay};
    curveVal[index] = obj;
    redraw();
}

private function redraw():void {
    thingy.graphics.clear();
    // loop through values and redraw
}
```

Comment: Of coarse you would have to add to this but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I could use a little explanation on this... What are 'cx', 'cy','ax' etc (CurveX, AnchorX?)? Are those values/vars that are put inside the curveVals array?

Comment: Also, could you explain what the colons + doubles do `cx:cx` (in the line `var obj:Object = {cx:cx,cy:cy,ax:ax,ay:ay};`)?